# Using WhenEvent for derivative of discontinuous function

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have a discontinuous function ($u(t)$, a square wave) and I would like `WhenEvent` to trigger when the signal goes high/low, i.e. when the value of $u(t)$ changes. I was hoping to use the derivative of $u(t)$ to determine this.

```
squareWave[t_, period_, duty_] := UnitBox[Mod[t/period, 1.]/(2. duty)]

system =  {x'[t] == u[t], WhenEvent[Mod[t, 0.5 τ], 
    u[t] -> squareWave[t, 2 τ, 0.2]], x[0] == 0, u[0] == 1, 
    WhenEvent[D[u[t]] > 0, Print[t]]};
params = {τ -> 1};
sol = NDSolve[system /. params, {x, u}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> u];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], u[t], u'[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "u(t)", "u'[t]"}]
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work? The output is:

[image: Output]

Comment: for me with 9.0.1 this gives the error "NDSolve::disder: Cannot take the derivative of discrete variable u." which seems quite self explaining. Other than that it seems to work, although as the squareWave only depends on time you wouldn't really need a WhenEvent. Which version/OS are you using?

Comment: I was using 9.0.0 on OS X, but updated to 9.0.1 and now I also see the proper error message. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Nasser Isn't the derivative of a square wave a series of dirac delta functions, each positioned where the amplitude changes?

Comment: @Nasser Good point! I've replaced `UnitBox` with `HeavisidePi`, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `D[u[t]]>0` doesn't work is that the derivative *at* the changing point doesn't exist. You can verify this by:

```
D[UnitBox[x], x]
```

> $\begin{array}{cc}
>  \{ 
> & \begin{array}{cc}
>  \text{Indeterminate} & x=\frac{1}{2}\lor x=-\frac{1}{2} \\
>  0 & \text{True} \\
> \end{array} \\
> \end{array}$

So the *predicate* in `WhenEvent` never come true.

If you refer to the documentation, in the details and options of `WhenEvent`, you may pay great attention to this

> *pred*  the predicate *pred* **becomes** True
>   f==0&&*pred*    f **crosses** zero and *pred* **is** True

In the first case, your *action* in `WhenEvent` is evaluated only when pred **jump from false to true**. While in the second case, *action* is evaluated when pred *keeps* true and f crosses zero.

So for your purpose, you may change the `WhenEvent` part to this

```
WhenEvent[{u[t] == 0, u[t] == 1}, Print[t]]
```